# How to convert List<Mono<T>> to Mono<List<T>>?

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I have a method that returns `Mono<Output>`:

```
interface Processor {
  Mono<Output> process(Input input);
}
```

And I want to execute this `processor` method for a collection:

```
List<Input> inputs = // get inputs
Processor processor = // get processor
List<Mono<Output>> outputs = inputs.stream().map(supplier::supply).collect(toList());
```

But instead of a `List<Mono<Output>>` I want to get `Mono<List<Output>>` that will contain aggregated results.

I tried `reduce`, but the final result looks very clumsy:

```
Mono<List<Output>> result = inputs.stream().map(processor::process)
    .reduce(Mono.just(new ArrayList<>()),
        (monoListOfOutput, monoOfOutput) ->
            monoListOfOutput.flatMap(list -> monoOfOutput.map(output -> {
              list.add(output);
              return list;
            })),
        (left, right) ->
            left.flatMap(leftList -> right.map(rightList -> {
              leftList.addAll(rightList);
              return leftList;
            })));
```

Can I achieve this with less code?

Comment: You could just wrap your call to "collect(toList)" with Mono.just and using map(Mono::block())

Comment: @manf Then I will get `Mono<List<Mono<Output>>>`. I need just `Mono<List<Output>>` instead. Added approach that I've tried already.

Comment: @manf I don't want to block.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you don't have to create stream for any reason, you could create Flux from your inputs, map it and collect list

```
Flux.fromIterable(inputs).flatMap(processor::process).collectList();
```

Comment: You can use the same approach even if you do start with `outputs` instead of `inputs` (edited my answer). But this is better.

Answer (score 11):

```
// first merge all the `Mono`s:
List<Mono<Output>> outputs = ...
Flux<Output> merged = Flux.empty();
for (Mono<Output> out : outputs) {
    merged = merged.mergeWith(out);
}

// then collect them
return merged.collectList();
```

or (inspired by Alexander's answer)

```
Flux.fromIterable(outputs).flatMap(x -> x).collectList();
```