# How to combine List<Mono<String>> in a big String?

Tags: java, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have created a List of String Monos `List<Mono<String>> myList`. And now I need to concatenate them in a big string.

When I initialize a `StringBuilder` and update it asyncronously, the empty line maybe returned.

```
//method body....

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

myList.forEach {
    mono ->
    mono.map{ str -> builder.append(str)}
}

return builder.toString() //<- is ""
```

How can I make the builder wait for the monos?

Comment: Convert the `List<Mono<String>>` to a `Mono<List<String>>` first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231537/how-to-convert-listmonot-to-monolistt.

Comment: @AndyTurner I can combine to Flux. But I don't know if it makes my life easier

Comment: I think the problem is bigger than that. You don't seem to understand two key concepts of Mono/Flux. 1: they represent **asynchronous** streams of data. 2. Nothing happens until you subscribe. I suggest you read the user guide of reactor. You subscribe to a Mono/FLux in order to make it start emitting events, and you will only be notified **later** when something is emitted. So, not subscribing to Monos, and hoping to have a result immediately, are two things that don't make much sense. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html

Comment: @JBNizet your comment does not contain any answer and makes a groundless assumption about my abilities

Comment: It's not groundless. I just looked at the code you submitted: it doesn't ever subscribe, and it assumes that you can get a result immediately, without blocking. So the logical conclusion is that you 're missing key concepts, hence my comment to explain where you're wrong, and what to do about it. A comment is not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to convert List of Monos to Flux and then reduce your flux to have one string which contains all your substrings. Then you have Mono that you can use still in async way. 
(You should always work on Mono/Flux if you want to keep async paradigm with project reactor)

Example:

```
    List<Mono<String>> listOfMonosWithString = Arrays.asList(Mono.just("a"), Mono.just("b"), Mono.just("c"));
    Flux<String> mergedMonos = Flux.fromIterable(listOfMonosWithString)
            .flatMapSequential(Function.identity());

    mergedMonos
            .reduce(String::concat)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .subscribe();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be flatMapSequantial()? (assuming the order in the final string should match the order of the monos)

Comment: Actually yes, we care about order I guess.
Good point, thank you ;)