# Is there a way to merge in Java Spring an unpredictable amount of Monos in a list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a Mono < List <(Some self-made object)>> method that takes in a single parameter of a list of URNs.

```
public Mono <List <MyObject>> loadMyObjectsFromUrnAsync (Iterable <String> urns) {...}
```

Depending on the number of URNs, I have to make a number of asynchronous HTTP requests, each of which is represented by a Mono. As I want the program to be able to move onto other parts of the program while running this method and executing all the requests, how do I go about zipping the various Monos and returning the result for the singular Mono?

```
... {
   List <Mono <MyObject>> myList = new Arraylist <Mono <MyObject>> ();
   while (urns.hasNext()) {
      // create a Mono HTTP request with the current iterated URN 
      myList.add(request); }
   return mono.zip(myList);
   }...
```

The code above obviously doesn't work, it's just there to hopefully make my question easier to undestand. I couldn't find any documentation online on how to zip a list of Monos without having to specify each Mono

Comment: Is it `Mono <List <MyObject>>` or `List <Mono <MyObject>>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert List<Mono<T>> to Mono<List<T>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53231537/how-to-convert-listmonot-to-monolistt)

Comment: @Andreas I want to zip a list of Monos that individually return an instance of MyObject; it's Mono <List <MyObject>> because I want to asynchronously run a Mono that has zipped asynchronous Monos within, similar to C# where a Task can have a return type of (List of) Tasks.WhenAll

Comment: @Ziumin not exactly, refer to my comment to Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above may not have been clearly conveyed, so I'll just rephrase it and then describe my solution. Hope this helps someone!

Also an important note: this solution is done in Java Spring using WebClient to execute asynchronous client-side requests to a remote server.

> Depending on the number of URNs, I have to make a number of asynchronous HTTP requests, each of which is represented by a Mono.

Let's say there is a function that takes in an ArrayList of HTTP endpoints and returns an ArrayList of type MyObject. I want this function to take these endpoints and execute a corresponding number of HTTP requests using Monos that will populate that number of MyObject POJOs (plain old Java objects), however, as the number of Monos will differ depending on the number of endpoints, I cannot explicitly define each Mono. I'm using Monos to allow me to execute these requests in parallel, or at the same time, as opposed to sequentially one by one, and I want to be notified when all my Monos have completed and can produce the instances of MyObject.

> As I want the program to be able to move onto other parts of the program while running this method and executing all the requests, how do I go about zipping the various Monos and returning the result for the singular merged stream when it completes?

The solution to organizing a set of unpredictable Monos is by **storing an Iterable of Monos and merging it in a flux that is then buffered and blocked to produce the Java objects!**

(It's important to understand what Monos and Fluxes are to fully understand this solution)

```
public Mono<MyObject> getOneObject(String endpoint) {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(endpoint)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(MyObject.class)
}
```

This function above retrieves one object based on one endpoint. Now, let's create an Iterable of Monos based on a given list of endpoints.

```
public Iterable<Mono<MyObject>> getMultipleObjects(ArrayList<String> endpoints) {
    ArrayList<Mono<MyObject>> monos = new ArrayList<Mono<MyObject>> ();
    for (String endpoint: endpoints) {
         monos.add(getOneObject(endpoint));
    }
    return monos;
}
```

This function above returns an ArrayList (cast to Iterable in the return statement) that is populated by iterating through the list of endpoints. Now, let's merge the iterable of monos into a singular flux!

```
public Flux<MyObject> mergeMultipleMonos(Iterable<Mono<MyObject>> multipleMonos) {
    return Flux.merge(multipleMonos);
}
```

Now, all you have to do is buffer and block the flux to produce the ArrayList of objects!

```
public ArrayList<MyObject> listOfObjects(Flux<MyObject> fluxOfObjects) {
    return fluxOfObjects.buffer().blockLast();
}
```

Flux.buffer() will collect all incoming values into a list, and Flux.blockLast() will subscribe to this flux and block indefinitely until the upstream signals its last value or completes.

And that is how an unpredictable number of Monos, in this case representing asynchronous client-side HTTP web requests, can be merged into a singular stream aka flux that will populate all the values when every request has returned!